# Desktop and Documents folders are hidden

Tags: macos

I recently noticed that `/Users/MyUserName/Desktop` and  `/Users/MyUserName/Documents` have been hidden. They are not hidden in the regular manner (they have no `.` before the folder name and cannot be reverted using `chflags nohidden /path/to/folder/` or `setfile -a v /path/to/folder/`.

**Here’s a screenshot of the folders:**
[image: Image of folders]

I still have all regular permissions to the folders.

Could someone help shine light on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your current Operating System?

Comment: I am running macOS Sierra, 10.12.2

Comment: Is it possible to put a snapshot in your question?

Comment: @Scorpion99 Done.

Comment: They don't look hidden.  Is there an error you get when opening them?

Comment: No error, they open fine. Only problem is that they can’t be seen without showing hidden files/folders, and they’re slightly greyed out.

Comment: Have you [stored your Desktop & Documents folders in iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985) (note that this is a new feature in macOS Sierra)?

Comment: I have stored Desktop and Documents in iCloud, does that hide them from user folder?